# IF ELSE Function through different datas sources

Tags: tableau-api

I have two data sources in my Tableau Sheet and i want to create an if else function for true or false.

The two data sources have the same column Name which is **Fahrzeug** and and there are values in first data source that has the same **Fahrzeug** *Value* as the other data source, and i Need a if else function which will give me **True** if there are the same values in both data sources and **False** if its not the same.

This is how the Tableau sheet Looks like.[image]

Examples of datasets :

First and the main dataset [image: First dataset]
Second dataset [image: Second dataset]

Comment: could you please provide samples of the two datasets? in addition, what's your level of detail in the workbook (related to the granularity of the sources)

Comment: @FabioFantoni i provided Pictures of datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to really know what will work best without knowing what intend to use that Boolean field for. Regardless, I find Tableau fairly poor for iterating through and comparing values in different tables, as that wasn't it's design. Best bet would be process than outside of Tableau, either Tableau Prep or write a script of some kind.

But one possibility using a pure Tableau desktop method would be to just create a new dataset that has a full outer join on the `[Fahrzeug]` field.

1. **Create a new datasource using a the full outer join on `[Fahrzueg]` in `FFE_Ausfalldaten.csv` and `FFE_Boxplot.csv`**

   - That gives you a null in the left dataset when it appears only in the right, and vice versa. With the same value in both [Fahrzeug] field's when it appears in both.
2. **Then create a calculated field in the new datasource called `[Fahrzeug_Bool]` or whatever you want**

   - `iif((ISNULL([Fahrzeug1])=True or ISNULL([Fahrzeug2])),FALSE,TRUE)`
   - this assigns False is either Fahrzeug field is null (i.e. only common in one file), True otherwise
3. **Then edit the datasource relationships** so the `[Fahrzeug]` fields in the individual fields (`FFEAusfalldaten.csv` and `FFEBoxplots.csv`) are linked to the corresponding `[Fahrzeug1]` and `[Fahrzeug2]` fields in the joined dataset.

   - Pull the individual fields into view along with the `[Fahrzeug_Bool]` field and validate they are `True` or `False` as expected